# Audio/Video Signal Questions, Are They On Topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I saw that [What are or where to find SDI record start/stop ancillary packet specification for Sony, Red or Panasonic](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4061/what-are-or-where-to-find-sdi-record-start-stop-ancillary-packet-specification-f) was deleted.  I wonder if questions like this really should be on topic though.  The nature of signals being used in an A/V production environment can have a significant impact on what can be done in an A/V sense.

Am I missing something else about why this was deleted?  Do we want to consider questions like this off topic or should we consider questions about A/V related signals that have potential application in the production realm to be on topic?

Comment: Hmmm, giving the question a second look, was it closed simply because it was looking for someone to find the specifications rather than asking about them?  If that's the case, then this can probably be ignored.

Comment: This question was deleted by the Community user.  Basically, it was a year old, with no votes and no answers.  I've undeleted it.  Be sure to upvote if you think it's a good question :)

Comment: Also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I believe that this kind of information is valuable within the scope of Audio/Visual production.  There are many real world problems that can not be effectively troubleshooted without at least some understanding of the signals involved.

Answer (score 2):

While I think that some signal questions may be better on Electronics (or even on Physics if the core of the question is about wave propagation etc) here we could say that impedance matching can be on topic, as can signal loss in cables, distortion due to sampling rates etc.

If a question here doesn't get any votes, answers or visibility and it could fit one of those other sites then sure, we should have the option to migrate it, but allow them to be on-topic here.